# JavaScript Convert YYYY-MM-DD-HH-MM-SS to Epoch

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, epoch

I have a date as string like this:

> 2018-05-29-13-56-00

I need to convert this **to epoch** so I can make calculations with other dates.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do that?
Thank you!

Comment: Split the string by `-`, extract the numbers, and create a date object from it, then call `getTime()` on the date object.

Comment: Date library moment.js will help you do both convetrting string to date object and do the calculations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this. Note the `d[1] - 1` because months are zero-based.

```js
const date = '2018-05-29-13-56-00';
const d = date.split('-');
const epoch = (new Date(d[0], d[1] - 1, d[2], d[3], d[4], d[5])).valueOf();
console.log(epoch);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com/), if you are okay with using that library.

```
moment('2018-05-29-13-56-00', 'YYYY-MM-DD-hh-mm-ss').format();
```